# Will entitymanager.merge() work on a cloned entity object

Tags: java, jpa

It's a basic question but I couldn't find much info on this.

The use case is following:
I did a search with a CriteriaQuery to find x records.
The last call I make in this method to launch the actual search is following:

```
getEntityManager().createQuery(query).setMaxResults(MAX_ROWS).getResultList())
```

So this means the records I'm getting back are attached to the entityManager.

Imagine I would deep clone those entities, change some values in those cloned entities and try to call entityManager.merge(clonedEntity). Will this work? Does the 'merge' methode check the 'equals' method in your entity to find the similar objects in the database and update these or won't this work and you need to change the entities attached to the entitymanager to be able to update those records in the database?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Merging is required only for detached entities.

Comment: Thanks for that, that's what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the objects that are controlled by the entitymanager, then you don't need to merge. A cloned entity is detached, so you need to persist it (if it doesn't have an id) and it will represent a new object, hence a new entry in the database.

If it does have an id, you can merge it. This depends on whether you use a generated id and if cloning also copies the id.

Comment: If you merge a detached entity that already has an id, JPA will _merge_ it with the existing entity, not create a new one. That's actually the goal of using merge instead of persist.